# Addition of $n$ points on elliptic curves over a finite field

Tags: algebraic-geometry, elliptic-curves, arithmetic-geometry

Let $E$ an elliptic curve over a finite field $\mathbb{F}_q$. Let $P_1, \dots, P_n \in E(\mathbb{F}_q) \backslash  \{\mathcal{O}\} $ be $n$ distinct rational points of $E$. Suppose there exists a rational point $P \in E(\mathbb{F}_q)$ and $P \notin \{\mathcal{O}, P_1, \dots, P_n \}$.

My question: Is it possible to guarantee that $P_1 \oplus \cdots \oplus P_n \neq \alpha P$ for any nonzero $\alpha \in \mathbb{Z}$ (i.e., $P_1 \oplus \cdots \oplus P_n \notin \langle P \rangle-\{ \mathcal{O} \}$)?

If it is not possible, are there some conditions for that?

Context: I want to show that a divisor $\alpha P + \beta \mathcal{O} - P_1 - \cdots - P_n$ with $\alpha+\beta=n$ is not principal (or give some conditions for this). Using that a divisor $D$ with $\deg D=0$ on $E$ is principal iff $D = \mathcal{O}$ in the group law, I get to my question since
$\alpha P \oplus \beta \mathcal{O} \oplus (-1) P_1 \oplus (-1) \cdots \oplus (-1) P_n = \alpha P \oplus (-1) P_1 \oplus (-1) \cdots \oplus (-1) P_n$

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The sum is a red herring. All you really want to know is, given two points $P$ and $Q$, how can you decide whether the one is a multiple of the other, right?

Comment: I suppose brute force works. Just calculate $P,2P,3P,\dots$ until you start repeating (which must happen, as there are only finitely many points over a finite field), and either you get $Q$ somewhere along the way, or you don't.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a counter-example.

It is a general fact that for a finite abelian group $A$ having odd torsion,
$$\sum_{a\in A}a=0.$$
Now suppose $|E(\mathbb F_q)|>2$. Then let $P\ne O\in E(\mathbb F_q)$, and let $\{P_1,\dots,P_n\}=E(\mathbb F_q)\backslash\{O,P\}$. Then by the above
$$P_1+\cdots+P_n=-P.$$

Comment: In the finite abelian group $C_4=\{0,1,2,3\}$ of order $4>2$, $0+1+2+3=2\ne0$.

Comment: Sorry yes A having odd torsion is enough.

Comment: So, you are assuming that the group of points on the curve over the finite field has odd torsion?

Comment: Yes, I am. With more work a counter-example for when the curve has >2 points can also be produced.